# Connection String For Access Databse On Other Computer

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I have developed a desktop application in dot net framework 3.5 using Microsoft access database in c#. I am connecting my application with the database on other computer using this connection string which is also working fine:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\192.168.1.101\Documents\database.mdb.
```

The computers are on same work group and I have placed this database.mdb file on other computer in shared folder name Documents and I can access it easily but the problem is I cannot place the database in a shared folder for security reasons, so I want to access this database on other computer without a shared folder.

Is there any way to do this? Please help me here.

Comment: Why can't you shift the database itself to that remote computer? Just curious.

Comment: Probably the best solution will be abandon access database (and all security issues it brings) and store your data in some RDBMS like MySQL, SQL Server Express or something like this.

Comment: Yes, database is on remote computer, how will i access it. I can't user other databases like mysql or sql server. How can i do this?

Comment: I also tried this connection string but it does not work Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\192.168.1.101\C:\database.mdb; Is there any way?

Comment: Instead of publicly sharing it, just give the user/machine(s) that need permission to access it.  To them, it will act the same as a public share, but others won't be able to access it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to put it in a public shared folder. 
You can create a special folder (e.g. C:\MySecureDataBaseFolder) where you just put this file. Then you give read/write permissions to that folder to the user(s) who is/are allowed to work with that database.
Now you either create DriveLetters for the shared folder or you connect it via "//OtherComputer/Shared..." syntax.